# OLEDBException: No value given for one or more required parameters in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parameters, oledbexception

I'm new to programming and am having a problem with a web application I am coding in VB.net. I have an Access database in my project and am using a parameterized query to retrieve information from it. The weird thing is, I use almost the same query on another page that works fine, but this one gives me teh "No value given for one or more required parameters" error. I have been searching most of the day and realize the question has been asked but can't find the solution to my problem. I think I am using the "?" correctly, have the right number of parameters in the right order, and everything is spelled right. Here is my code:

```
 Dim strWthStn As String
    strWthStn = cboRainProb2.Text
    Dim strWthStnParm As New OleDb.OleDbParameter()
    strWthStnParm.Value = strWthStn

    Dim strMonth As String
    strMonth = cboRainProb.Text
    Dim strMonthParm As New OleDb.OleDbParameter()
    strMonthParm.Value = strMonth

    Dim sql As String 'Query to select the station for rainfall probability values

    sql = "SELECT 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010 " &
    "FROM Rainfall Probability " &
    "WHERE Station = ?" &
    "AND Mth = ?"

    'Connects to the Access database and selects data based on query
    Dim AccessConnect As String
    AccessConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\Megan\Visual Studio Projects\DroughtCalculatorND_Web\DroughtCalculatorND_Web\NDStations.mdb"
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim selectCommand As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(strWthStnParm)
    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(strMonthParm)
    conn.ConnectionString = AccessConnect
    conn.Open()

    'Reads the data into a list
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader =
        selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    Dim RainByYear As New List(Of Double)
    reader.Read()
    RainByYear.Add(reader("1999"))
    RainByYear.Add(reader("2000"))
    RainByYear.Add(reader("2001"))
    RainByYear.Add(reader("2002"))
    RainByYear.Add(reader("2003"))
    RainByYear.Add(reader("2004"))
    RainByYear.Add(reader("2005"))
    RainByYear.Add(reader("2006"))
    RainByYear.Add(reader("2007"))
    RainByYear.Add(reader("2008"))
    RainByYear.Add(reader("2009"))
    RainByYear.Add(reader("2010"))

    RainByYear.Sort()
```

etc.

The program errors at the Dim reader at OleDBDataReader line. I used a breakpoint there to check everything and both parameters had the correct value. I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "correct value" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Names that have spaces require brackets:

```
"FROM [Rainfall Probability] "
```

Your numbered field names might also:

```
SELECT [1999], [2000] etc...
```

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to fix the problem.